# How do I filter my array of objects by date?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a showAppointments variable which is an object. I then have a loop that initially sets showAppointments[g] (with g being which specific day the appointment is created in), to an array. In the loop I then push data in the form of an object into the showAppointments[g] array.

.ts file

```
export class CalendarHoursComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   allDates = []; allMonths = [];
  appointments: IAppointmentsByDate[];
  currentDate: Date = new Date(); firstSunday: Date; 
  month = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  ticketId: number; ticket_entries: ITicketsView1[]; showAppointments={}; showHours = {}; showRecAppointments={};

load(delta: number) {
    if (delta!=0) this.currentDate = this.addMonths(this.currentDate, delta);
    if (this.isTicketManager()) {
        this.server.getAppointmentsForDateRange(this.userId, this.firstSunday.getMonth() + 1,
        lastSaturday.getDate(), lastSaturday.getFullYear(), this.endMonth(lastSaturday, 34), this.addDays(lastSaturday, 34),
        this.endYear(lastSaturday, 34), r=>  {this.setAppointments(r) });
      });
    } else {
        this.server.getAppointmentsForDateRange(this.userId, this.firstSunday.getMonth() + 1,
        lastSaturday.getDate(), lastSaturday.getFullYear(), this.endMonth(lastSaturday, 34), this.addDays(lastSaturday, 34),
        this.endYear(lastSaturday, 34), r=> this.setAppointments(r));
      });
    }



private setAppointments(i: IAppointmentsByDate[]) {
    this.allDates.forEach(e=> {
      e.forEach(g=> {
        g.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        this.showAppointments[g] = [];
        this.showRecAppointments[g] = [];
          let f = i.filter(e2=> {
            let i2 = new Date(e2.endTime); i2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            return i2.valueOf() == g.valueOf();
          });
        if(f) {

          f.forEach(e3=> {
            if(e3.recurrance_id > 1) {
              this.showAppointments[g].push({
                id: e3.id,
                text: e3.customer + " " + "Ticket #" + e3.ticket_id + " " + this.datepipe.transform(e3.startTime, 'hh:mm a') + " - " + this.datepipe.transform(e3.endTime, 'hh:mm a' + " Recurring"),
                date: new Date(e3.startTime),
                time: this.datepipe.transform(e3.startTime, 'hh:mm a')
              });
            } else {
              this.showAppointments[g].push({
                id: e3.id,
                text: e3.customer + " " + "Ticket #" + e3.ticket_id + " " + this.datepipe.transform(e3.startTime, 'hh:mm a') +" - " + this.datepipe.transform(e3.endTime, 'hh:mm a'),
                date: new Date(e3.startTime),
                time: this.datepipe.transform(e3.startTime, 'hh:mm a')
              });
            }

          });
          console.log(this.showAppointments[g]);
          this.showAppointments[g].sort((a,b)=> {
            return a.time.localeCompare(b.time);
         });
        }
```

.html file

```
<tr *ngFor="let w of allDates">
        <td #tdElement class='days clickable' *ngFor="let d of w"
          (click)="tdElement.classList.contains('do-not-click') ? false : openMenu($event,d)">
          <span class="top-left">{{d.getDate()}}</span>
          <h4 *ngFor="let b of showHours[d]" class="center">{{ b.hours }}</h4>
          <ul>
            <li class="sticky-note" *ngFor="let a of showAppointments[d]"
              (mouseenter)="tdElement.classList.add('do-not-click')"
              (mouseleave)="tdElement.classList.remove('do-not-click')"
              (click)="openMenu2($event,d,a.id)">
              {{ a.text }}
            </li>
```

The idea as I said, is that I am placing data on a calendar for that particular day. So when I console.log(this.showAppointments[g]) I get something like this:

[image]

I thought the filtered method would work below since I am comparing date values and returning only the appointments with dates equal to or after the current date which is what I need. But when I console.log it, I get all empty arrays with no objects inside.

```
this.appointments[g].filter(e=> e.date.valueOf() >= new Date().valueOf())
```

So, any suggestions on how to fix the problem?

Comment: is e.date an actual Date object..? Also - please use descriptive variable names... this is quite difficult to read..

Comment: @MikeOne Sorry, it is quite a lot. In the screen shot above you can see I have an array of objects where date is actually a key in each object and I use e.date to access the values inside date key. But the information I have given according to Boug is an array of arrays rather than an array of objects.

Comment: Right, got it. Still - if e.date is not an actual Date object (but maybe just a date string) - your comparison will probably fail.. If that is the case you'll have to do new Date(e.date).valueOf

Comment: @MikeOne Yes I do set the value of the Date key to an actual Date object. If you look where I push the objects into this.showappointment[g], you will see I have a key named date: new Date(e3.startTime).

Comment: @Randy Goldsmith check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

After another day of letting this problem sink in and many console.logs, the problem was not with the logic or the placement of the filter. The problem was I was still looping and returning the old this.showAppointments[g] array, not the filtered one. So what I did to solve the problem was set:

```
this.showAppointments[g] = this.showAppointments[g].filter(r=> r.date.valueOf() >= new Date().valueOf)
```

And so in my ngFor in the html, it loops over the newly filtered array.